# how to show data graphic at web page

Tags: jquery, graphics

i have an input form and table input data at DB...
after that i want make some page that just consist of graphic...for make a graphic i will use data from DB..
what program to make it??i hope that program can work together with jquery and php..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a bunch of data points, R[RDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) is very efficient. But it could take some time to setup.

PHP bindings for [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/) is very straight forward and has a built in javascript library.

Comment: I too recommend Google Chart API